# How was the assumption made on half will have i < j?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have been reading "Cracking the Coding Interview 6th Edition".. On Chapter 0 - Big O, I have problem understanding an assumption made to a problem on Example 3.

```
void printUnorderedPairs(int[] array){
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Under *What It Means* section, it assumed that:

> There are N^2 total pairs. Roughly half of those will have i < j and the remaining half will have i > j. This code goes through roughly n^2/2 pairs so it does O(N^2) work.

My question is, how was the assumption made on ***Roughly half of those will have i < j and the remaining half will have i > j*** done? Can someone explain it to me please?

Thanks!

Comment: @ybungalobill , sorry but I had a typo with the code. I just edited it now.

Comment: Draw a grid on paper, write 1..N across the top and 1..N down the side. Color the squares where i < j: 
It's a triangle so about half the sheet (excluding the diagonal where i = j).  And j is always > i since the j loop starts at i+1.

Comment: @IanMercer: Thanks! This visually helps however, can this be proven in other ways not just by illustration? I mean, is there an underlying mathematical thought that you can do?

Comment: Think of all the pairs (i,j) where 0 <= i < n and and 0 <= j < n arranged on a grid with (0,0) at the upper left, (n-1,n-1) at the lower right, (0, n-1) at the upper right, and (n-1,0) at the lower left like the indices in a standard square matrix. There are  n^2 pairs. All those with i < j form the upper right triangle of the square.  All those with i > j form the lower left triangle.  Each triangle is roughly half the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can try to think about this assumption, I quite like the "geometric" suggestion from @IanMercer in the comments.   Here is another:

**What is an unordered pair**
An unordered pair is a pair of integers `(i,j)` where `i` and `j` is in the domain `(1, N)`. (They can take any value from 1 to N).

**How many pairs are there?**
 `i` can be of any value from 1 to `N`, and `j` can be of any value from 1 to `N`.  Any combination of `i` forms a valid pair. So there are are `N*N` pairs.

**Among all the pairs, how many pairs are there that `i < j`**
Note that for any pair `(a,b)` where `a` is smaller than `b`, there exists a counterpart `(b,a)` (same values but flipped).  So there is an equal amount of pairs where `i<j` as there are pairs 'i>j'.

So what is this confusing **roughly** part? It is because of all those `N*N` pairs there are some where neither `i<j` nor `j>i`, and those are precisely the `N` pairs where `i==j`.

The `N*N` pairs are thus divided into three parts `(those where i < j)`, `(those where j> i)` and `(those where i==j)`. Since first two are much larger `O(N**2)/2` vs. the last group which has only `N` elements, we can state that **roughly** half have the property that `i<j`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation about the assumption! I totally get it now. My lack of understanding was for the reason that I didnt really get the basics of unordered pairs. Thank you!